# Speed up Truecrypt decryption with rescue disk

Tags: truecrypt, decryption

Is there a possibility to speed up the decryption of a volume while using the rescue disk?

My Windows crashed and I am not able to boot Windows. Unfortunately the decryption of my 300GB Hard Disk will take my approx. 600 days! Is there any chance to speed up the decryption?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Locate the bottleneck and decide how it can be removed.

For instance:

- If you see that the CPU activity is locked at 100%, it may mean that the bottleneck is there. Try to do the restoration using another machine having a more powerful CPU.
- Are you using a USB external disk? USB may slow, consider an alternative way to connect your disk if the bottleneck is here. In all case ensure that your are not using USB 1 ports which are really too slow.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I currently have a Pentium i5 and I cannot see how is the work load of the CPU. I am using a avarage hdd. Is it possible to rent a powerful machine for this task on amazon web service?

Comment: Use "another machine" probably meant: "use a more powerful machine of yourself or a friend". Uploading 300GB will take even longer (I guess) than your slow (local) decryption. And outsourcing this to the cloud may be not a good idea is you originally wanted to protect your data and not let it be stored un-encrypted in the internet...

Comment: ( there is no such thing as a Pentium i5....

Comment: Sorry I mean Intel i5... Thanks guys I will try to find a more powerful machine